# Update tinymce html content in vue 3 (nuxtjs) mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, tinymce

I have the following vue3 page in nuxt.js. I have globally disabled SSR.

```js
<script setup>
    function setHtml() {
        tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<p>test</p>');
    }
</script>

<template>
    <Navbar/>
    <editor
      api-key="no-api-key"
      :init="{
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'lists advlist link image emoticons',
        toolbar: 'styleselect | forecolor backcolor | font-size bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link image emoticons'
      }"
    />
    
    <button @click="setHtml()">
        Update html
    </button>

    <br>

    <textarea id="htmlOutput" style="width: 100%; height: 50px;"></textarea>
</template>
  
<script>
    import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

    export default {
        mounted() {
            tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<p>test</p>');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, I want to update the html of the editor to `<p>test</p>` Directly after the component is loaded. For this I should use `mounted()`. This results in the following error:

```js
[nuxt] error caught during app initialization ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
```

I tried to create a function called `setHtml()`, which is called through a button. This does work. So, I figure either one of the following two things happens:

1. The scope of `mounted()` has no access to `tinymce`
2. The editor has not been successfully loaded whenever `mounted()` is executed

How can I update the html contents of my editor, directly after mounting the page?

[Link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vibrant-rain-7762dl?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue%3A32%2C1-32%2C39)

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] (using codesandbox.io or a similar service). What you shared has no information about versions used and, because it's not runnable, it's not debuggable.

Comment: @tao I have added a link to a sandbox. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: You can set the initial value using [initial-value](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/vue-ref/#initial-value). You can also use [v-model](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sharp-dewdney-28xlk6?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.vue%3A18%2C5). Your question seems a bit of a XY problem. Rather than asking how to get access to the instance, you might want to ask how to achieve what you're actually trying to achieve. You can get access to the instance by placing a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) on the `<editor>` component.